# meteor version compatibility 1.1.0.3 vs 1.1.0.2

Tags: meteor

I got error message, running meteor 1.1.0.3

```
> ~/.meteor/meteor --version 
Meteor 1.1.0.3
> ~/.meteor/meteor
Sorry, this project uses Meteor 1.1.0.2, which is not installed and could not be downloaded. Please check to make sure that you are online.
```

Shouldn't 1.1.0.3 be backward compatible? Can someone tell me how to get earlier version of Meteor

Comment: did you run `meteor update` in your project folder?

Comment: my meteor is on later version 1.1.0.3 than the project 1.1.0.2

Comment: yes, but meteor uses strict version requirements. So meteor tool will try to download the exact version you specified. If you are indeed not online and can't change that, then just edit your `.meteor/release` file.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor uses strict version requirements. So `meteor-tool` will try to download the exact version you specified in your project. If you are indeed not online and can't change that, or just want to start using the latest version that you seem to have installed, then just edit your `.meteor/release` file and manually change the meteor version to 1.1.0.3.